# How do I train only the new weights?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

Consider a (dense) layer of 10 units. I would like now to add another (single) unit to this layer. But how do I make sure that the previous 10 weights are not trained, and only the new one gets trained?

Comment: Why would you want to do such a thing? By adding the new unit, you may also need to change the previously trained units.

Comment: I think this question may be useful. But can you please create a _very simple_ Tensorflow program which illustrates your situation (so that an answerer can also provide an answer with a concrete solution/implementation)?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a list of variables to different optimizers. One for training the first 10 units the other one for training the other one in conjunction with a `tf.cond()` so you can have two branches in your graph for when you want to use only 10 or 11 neurons. You can also play with `tf.stop_gradient()` it really depends on your use case.

Without more informations it is difficult to answer but somewhere along the lines of:

```
import tensorflow as tf

choose_branch=tf.placeholder(tf.bool)
w_old=tf.Variable(np.random.normal(size=(1,10)).astype("float32"))
b=tf.Variable(np.zeros((1)).astype("float32"))
x=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,size=[None,1])
target=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,size=[None,1])

hidden_old=tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x,w_old)+b)

w_proj_old=tf.Variable(np.random.normal(size=(10,1)).astype("float32")

y_old=tf.matmul(hidden_old, w_proj_old)

cost_old=tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_old-target))

w_plus=tf.Variable(np.random.normal(size=(1,1)).astype("float32"))
w_proj_plus=tf.Variable(np.random.normal(size=(1,1)).astype("float32")

w_proj_new=tf.concat([w_proj_old,w_proj_plus],axis=1)

w_new=tf.concat([w_old,w_plus],axis=1)
hidden_new=tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x,w_new,axis=1))+b))

y_new=tf.matmul(hidden_new, w_proj_new)

cost_new=tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_new-target))

opt_old=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.001)
opt_new=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.0001)

train_step_old=opt_old.minimize(var_list=[w_old,b,w_proj_old,b])
train_step_new=opt_new.minimize(var_list=[w_plus,w_proj_plus])
y=tf.cond(choose_branch,lambda: y_old,lambda: y_new)
```

Careful the code was not tested.

Comment: It would be very useful if you could provide a concrete and reproducible (Tensorflow) example for each of your suggestions.

Comment: Hey, the code is good, but the thing is, I don't have the data when I train 11 neurons. Imagine training MNIST on first 8 digits, then calling the same model later and training it for 9 without disturbing the first 8. This term is called catastrophic forgetting. I need to train the 9th neuron without disturbing the first 8.

Comment: @BlackSpecter do not expect people on stackoverflow to come up with answers to questions you did not ask. The code will not disturb the neurones in w_old and _w_proj_old but it will change the final output and could lead to catastroph forgetting. This issue is still under investigation and the ways to deal with it are complex and numerous. It seems to me that you do not understand how stackoverflow works. It is meant for people to ask a very specific and narrow code question in contrast to cross validated which would maybe give you a litterature review on catastrophic forgetting.

Answer (score 0):

To do this kind of advanced operations I find it easier to switch to the lower API of tensorflow.

A fully connected layer is usually defined as a matrix multiplication. For example, suppose your previous layer has `128` features, and you want to implement a fully connected layer with `256` features. You could write

```
batch_size = 128
num_in = 128
num_out = 256

h = tf.zeros((batch_size, num_in)) # actually, the output of the previous layer

# create the weights for the fully connected layer
w = tf.get_variable('w', shape=(num_in, num_out))
# compute the output
y = tf.matmul(h, w)
# -- feel free to add biases and activation
```

Now let's suppose you have trained `w` and want to add some extra neurons to this layer. You could create an extra variable holding the extra weights, and concatenate it with the existing one.

```
num_out_extra = 10
# now w is set to trainable=False, we don't want its values to change
w = tf.get_variable('w', shape=(num_in, num_out), trainable=False)
# our new weights
w_extra = tf.get_variable('w_extra', shape=(num_in, num_out_extra))
w_total = tf.concat([w, w_extra], axis=-1)
y = tf.matmul(h, w_total)
# now y has 266 features
```

You will need to initialize all the weights one way or the other of course.